# Can Set an array to get all of variable and put them into a database or data gridview in C# WindowsForm?

Tags: c#

I have some variable that whit a save button get them from the user like this:

```
private void Savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedCowType = InputCalculator.CalculateCowTypeInput(this);
        CowAgeMonth = Convert.ToInt32(CowAgenumBox.Value);
        CowWeightKg = Convert.ToInt32(CowWeightnumBox.Value);
        DaysPregDay = Convert.ToInt32(DaysPregnumBox.Value);
        DaysInMilkDay = Convert.ToInt32(DaysInMilknumBox.Value);
        LactationNumber = Convert.ToInt32(LactationNumbernumBox.Value);
        FirstCalfMonth = Convert.ToInt32(FirstCalfnumBox.Value);
        CalfIntMonth = Convert.ToInt32(CalfIntnumBox.Value);
        BCS05 = Convert.ToDouble(BCSnumBox.Value);
        CalfWeightKg = Convert.ToDouble(CalfWeightnumBox.Value);
        CalfTempC = Convert.ToDouble(CalfCurrentTempnumBox.Value);
    }
```

and for example I have a `dataGridview` whit 2 columns (variable text, variable value)

is there any way to automatically these 2 columns fill whit may variable texts and values no matter how much variable it is??

Comment: `is there any way` yes, is it the best way, no.  Why not a Cow table to save typed values to specific columns?

Comment: I Have many more variable and I just write some of the here, and this variable are comes from many circumstances depended on cow type, management status and so on ... , and in the end I use these variable to put them in many formule. And Number of my variable is different depend on cow type, the reason of my question is that I want to show the variable value to the user and if user verified them then my calculations runs

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Add columns and data to datagridview](http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-add-column.htm)